# How to get the UTC time in years and months

Tags: php, date, datetime, utc

I want to know how I could get the UTC time in year and months?
I've scraped the UTC date and time from a website, but I have been to asked to show the full UTC format such as (2014-07-31 22:00:00), the problem I'm facing now is that our current time is 1 hour ahead than UTC time.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 $date_time = date("Y-m", $time_now) . "-". $wxInfo['DAY'] . " " . $wxInfo['HOUR'] . ":" . $wxInfo['MINUTE'] . ":00";
```

As you can see, for the Y-m(year and month) I use local time, but the DAY, HOUR, MINUTE values from the website which is in UTC. This $date_time is updated every half hour, if they update on "2014-07-31 23:00:00", our current time is "2014-08-01 00:00:00". so my code will output:

```
    2014-08-31 23:00:00
```

How can I convert to the right UTC year and month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [`DateTimeZone()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)

```
// Set time to local time "now" 
$datetime = new DateTime();
// Change timezone to UTC
$datetime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// Echo datetime in desired format
echo $datetime->format('Y-m');
```

Comment: How can i test is right? i mean can i change the DateTime() = "2014-08-01 00:00:00" to  test the code to see can get the right month is 07 not 08?

Comment: Just pass the date/time to the first `DateTime()` as a parameter: `$datetime = new DateTime('2014-08-01 00:00:00');`

Answer (score 0):

The solution John Conde suggested works well for displaying dates and times in a specific timezone.

In your case, I think you may want to set the timezone to UTC on the whole script, so all your calls to date() and DateTime->format() automatically use UTC. That is really simple to do: at the beginning of your script, write:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

PHP will then use UTC as a timezone everywhere. See manual: http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set